# AS 2.0 - Passing xml file path as a flashvars in onClipEvent

Tags: xml, actionscript-2, flashvars

I want to pass xml file path dynamically using flashvars.
It works ok in Onrollover and Onrollout events. But not in onClipEvent.
Below is the code I am using -

```
onClipEvent (load) 
{
cnetXML = new XML();
cnetXML.ignoreWhite = true;
cnetXML.onLoad=extractData;
var xmlfile = xmlpath;
cnetXML.load(xmlfile);
function extractData(success)
{
rootHandler=this.firstChild.childNodes[23].childNodes[5].firstChild.nodeValue;
if (rootHandler)
gotoAndStop(2);
}
}
```

If I replace xmlpath in above script with actual link, it works ok.
Please let me know what I am missing here?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

I think I spoke too soon.
I have found answer to my questions
Instead of assigning flashvars to another variable I am using below code -

```
    onClipEvent (load) {
cnetXML = new XML();
cnetXML.ignoreWhite = true;
cnetXML.onLoad=extractData;
cnetXML.load(_level0.xmlPath);
function extractData(success)
{
rootHandler=this.firstChild.childNodes[23].childNodes[5].firstChild.nodeValue;
if (rootHandler)
gotoAndStop(2);
}
}
```

xmlPath is defined in html as

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="xmlPath=http://www.domainname.com/graphics/test.xml" />
```

Also in embed tag as

```
<embed src="floorplan-amusa-test4.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="752" height="458" name="floorplan-amusa-test4" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" FlashVars="xmlPath=http://www.domainname.com/graphics/test.xml" />
```